# jbutton setVisible(false) setting back to setVisible(true) not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton, grid-layout, visible

[image]I have a code that when I click the jButton it should set to not visible and the other JButton which is already set to FALSE should be TRUE, the setVisible(true) is not working.

```
buttonGrid[row][col] = new JButton();
add(buttonGrid[row][col]);
buttonGrid[row][col].setVisible(false);
```

that code work when I set to false and if I set back to true. it is not working

```
JButton selectedBtn = (JButton) evt.getSource();
            selectedBtn.setVisible(true);

            for (int row = 0; row < buttonGrid.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < buttonGrid[row].length; col++) {

                    if(buttonGrid[row][col] == selectedBtn){
                        if ((row-1)>=0 && !buttonGrid[row - 1][col].isVisible()) {
                            System.out.println("1");
                            int c = row-1;

                            buttonGrid[c][col] = selectedBtn;
                            buttonGrid[c][col].setVisible(true);
                            buttonGrid[row][col].setVisible(false);
                        }
                            *
                            *
                            *
```

what I want is I'll try to click the button number 2. The button number 3 should be visible and the button number 2 be invisible.

Comment: plz provide a runable example.what !are you cliking on invisible button?

Answer (score 1):

You have to refresh the JPanel by using following methods

- `panel.revalidate();`
- `panel.repaint();`