# Jbutton Is Disappearing Even Though I call .setVisible(true)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am making a basic platformer game and I need to make it so that every time you jump all the platforms that are below where you jumped disappear and every platform above moves down. It is still in development so just ignore some of the things that are commented out and the messy mode.

Basically, my problem is that when I try to clear all the platforms below the one that you clicked it works fine using this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
  if(platforms[i] == null) {
    continue;
  }
  if(parameters[i][1] > y) {
    platforms[i].setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

However later when I try to use .setvisible(true) on the platform that you clicked it doesn't work. Here is the full code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main implements ActionListener {
  static JFrame frame;
  static JPanel panel;
  //static JLabel title;
  //static JLabel expl;
  static JButton[] platforms;
  static Random random;
  static boolean playing;
  static int[][] parameters;
  static int platformsMade;
  static int clicked;
  static int preClicked;
  static int score;
  static int lives;
  static int standing;
  static int speed;
  static double gravity;
  static int jump;
  static String action;
  public Main(int seed) throws Exception {
    frame = new JFrame("Snakes 'n' Adders");
    panel = new JPanel(null);
    //title =  new JLabel("Snakes 'n' Adders", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    //expl = new JLabel("");
    platforms = new JButton[100000];
    random = new Random();
    parameters = new int[100000][5];
    lives = 3;
    speed = 10;
    gravity = 9.81;
    jump = 5;
    action = "";
    //panel.add(title);
    //panel.add(expl);
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    random.setSeed(seed);
    panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    //title.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 50));
  }
  public void drawPlatform(int x, int y, int w, int h, int colour) {
    platforms[platformsMade] = new JButton();
    platforms[platformsMade].addActionListener(this);
    platforms[platformsMade].setBounds(x, y, w, h);
    switch(colour) {
      case 0:
        platforms[platformsMade].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        break;
      case 1:
        platforms[platformsMade].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        break;
      case 2:
        platforms[platformsMade].setBackground(Color.RED);
        break;
      case 3:
        platforms[platformsMade].setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        break;
      case 4:
        platforms[platformsMade].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        break;
    }
    parameters[platformsMade][0] = x;
    parameters[platformsMade][1] = y;
    parameters[platformsMade][2] = w;
    parameters[platformsMade][3] = h;
    parameters[platformsMade][4] = colour;
    panel.add(platforms[platformsMade]);
    platforms[platformsMade].setVisible(true);
    panel.repaint();
    platformsMade++;
  }
  public void movePlatforms(int distance, int i) {
    if(platforms[i] == null) {
      NullPointerException end = new NullPointerException();
      throw end;
    }
    //this.drawPlatform(parameters[i][0], parameters[i][1] + distance, parameters[i][2], parameters[i][3], parameters[i][4]);
    //platforms[i].setVisible(false);
    platforms[i].setBounds(parameters[i][0], parameters[i][1] + distance, parameters[i][2], parameters[i][3]);
    parameters[i][1] = parameters[i][1] + distance;
  }
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    preClicked = clicked;
    for(int i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
      if(event.getSource() == platforms[i]) {
        clicked = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    int y = parameters[clicked][1];
    for(int i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
      if(platforms[i] == null) {
        continue;
      }
      if(parameters[i][1] > y) {
        platforms[i].setVisible(false);
      }
      else {
        this.movePlatforms(150, i);
      }
      this.movePlatforms(150, clicked);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= random.nextInt(2); i++) {
      this.drawPlatform(random.nextInt(500), random.nextInt(500), 50, 50, random.nextInt(4));
    }
    /*for(int i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
      if(platforms[i] == null) {
       continue; 
      }
      if(platforms[i].getY() > frame.getY() - platforms[i].getHeight()) {
        platforms[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }*/
    platforms[clicked].addActionListener(this);
    platforms[clicked].setVisible(true);
    standing = clicked;
    for(int i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
      if(platforms[i] == null) {
        continue;
      }
      if(clicked == i) {
        platforms[i].setText("|");
      }
      else {
        platforms[i].setText("");
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Main sna = new Main(7845);
    //title.setVisible(true);
    //expl.setVisible(false);
    //Thread.sleep(5000);
    //title.setVisible(false);
    //expl.setVisible(true);
    //Thread.sleep(40000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      sna.drawPlatform(random.nextInt(500), random.nextInt(500), 50, 50, random.nextInt(4));
      }
      int ticks = 0;
      platforms[standing].setText("|");
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to refresh the JPanel as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017159/jbutton-setvisiblefalse-setting-back-to-setvisibletrue-not-working

Comment: `frame.setVisible(true);` should be the last line in the constructor, after all GUI is placed, sized... and wrapped into `invokeLater()`, please to read [Initial Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)